# Get form size of PARENT of current Panel

Tags: c#, forms, size

I'm running this code to create a BMP over my app when a dialog opens to reduce confusion for users on what cannot be accessed (until dialog is closed).

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(DisplayRectangle.Width, DisplayRectangle.Height);
            using (Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
            {
                G.CompositingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingMode.SourceOver;
                G.CopyFromScreen(this.PointToScreen(new Point(0, 0)), new Point(0, 0), this.DisplayRectangle.Size);
                double percent = 0.60;
                Color darken = Color.FromArgb((int)(255 * percent), Color.Black);
                using (Brush brsh = new SolidBrush(darken))
                {
                    G.FillRectangle(brsh, this.DisplayRectangle);
                }
            }

            // put the darkened screenshot into a Panel and bring it to the front:
            using (Panel p = new Panel())
            {
                p.Location = new Point(0, 0);
                p.Size = this.ClientRectangle.Size;
                p.BackgroundImage = bmp;
                this.Controls.Add(p);
                p.BringToFront();

                // display your dialog somehow:
                frmcollecting frmcollecting = new frmcollecting(pxid);
                frmcollecting.ShowDialog();
```

The issue is that it creates the bmp over the Panel (pnlActive), however I want it over the whole app. How can I get the dimenions and change the DisplayRectangle to "frmMainPage"?

Comment: `this.Parent.DisplayRectangle`? or maybe even better `this.FindForm().DisplayRectangle`?

Comment: Nope still jsut the panel. Probably because the button is the control and findform just finds the panel still!  Thanks for trying though.